# Bending arrows in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In `Tikz`, I would like to bend an arrow like the one between `$H_2O$` and `$O_2$` in this figure:

[image]

I'm able to have a bended line between `$H_2O$` and `$O_2$`, but it's not touching the photophosphorylation node…

How can I do that?

Comment: Fow on #latex found the beginning of a solution : http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/DExfrO7T . The problem is that the arrow is "broken" when it touches the circle.

Comment: Hey, cool diagram. Post the code, please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is most easily done by using the nodes placement, and a `to` command. You will then be able to achieve the desired result.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (-2,1) (H2O) {H2O};
  \node[fill=blue] at (2,0) (Photo) {Photophosphorylation};
  \node at (-2,-1) (O2) {O2};
  \draw[->] (H2O.east) to[out=0,in=90] (Photo.west) to[out=-90,in=0] (O2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: picture]

You can then always align them in ingenious ways using matrices or whatever.